# Как реализовать класс (вызов объекта класса как класс)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Помогите с проблемкой нужно реализовать класс, конструктор которого принимает аргумент- длину строки. Объект этого класса при вызове получает на вход один аргумент- строку произвольной длины и возвращает срез на длину строки.
Я написал вот это:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, length, *args):
        self.length = length
        self.string = args

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self.string)[:self.length]
```

Но работает оно только если передавать 2 аргумента сразу:

```
a = MyClass(5, "abracadabra")
print(a) # вадает abrac
```

А должно работать так:

```
a = MyClass(5)
res = a("abracadabra")
print(res) # должно выдать abrac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы объект класса можно было вызывать нужным вам образом, добавьте такой метод в класс:

```
def __call__(self, *args):
    self.string = args
    return self
```

Но учтите, что при этом меняется внутреннее состояние объекта `a`, лучше так всё-таки не делать, а создавать новые экземпляры класса с нужным состоянием обычным образом. Хотя случаи, конечно, разные бывают.